# Creating static IP for heroku to connect to external firewall

Tags: heroku, rackspace, static-ip-address

I'm trying to connect to ObjectRocket with my Heroku app, I'm running into a little problem where I can't seem to set a static IP (tried Proximo for that).

ObjectRocket requires me to define all IP's connecting to the database, so I need a non-dynamic IP for my heroku app.

How could I create this, or is this not possible with Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this answer to see how to use NGINX as a reverse proxy.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874505/1345865

http://blog.talenox.com/post/107675614745/how-to-setup-static-ip-on-heroku

If in your case where you require a outbound reverse proxy, setup an AWS instance and use NGINX to point it to ObjectRocket as your backend