# Convert Curl to JS/TS -X parameter

Tags: typescript, rest, curl

Hi whilist testing another part of code, I still can't find the solution. However:

```
curl -x "http://proxyaddress" -L "http://targetaddress"
```

Returns correct information, but I can't get it working in JS/Typescript. I'm using typescript with angular, but I can't get this proxy to work. What options should I set for this basic request?

Comment: well what have you tried? did you check the console? are there errors? what snippet of code are you using in js?

Comment: I wrote about this more in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242822/how-to-set-angular-proxy-using-quotaguard-using-node-js-server 

At first I thought that CORS is caused by running it locally, but after deploying to heroku cloud issue persists...